# OSX env variables for c++ development

Tags: c++, xcode, osx-snow-leopard

With visual studio there is an start menu option open a terminal window with all of the paths and environment variables setup to use the compiler.

Is there an equivalent for XCode or is there somewhere I find out what needs setting for this to work?

I am trying to get the boost libraries compiled but am just getting a tone of errors related to simple stuff. I have set some some of what I think should b required (include and lib paths) but I am obviously still missing some.

Martin

Comment: On OS X the Terminal environment is set up to use the compiler by default. You do have to have the command line tools installed though. Prior to Xcode 4.3 the command line tools were an optional install item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode uses gcc and llvm-clang. So the environment variables settings are the same as those.

But if all you want is to have boost available to your project, it may be easier to just install MacPort and build/install boost with it: http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=boost

MacPort supports many, many, many tools and libraries. It will make your life developing on OS X a lot easier.

Comment: What do you mean Vlad? One of the main reasons I used boost in the original project was so that I could eventually port it to OSX.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're really asking about build settings -- the variables that are available at compile time to define things like paths and options. You can set these on a per-project or per-target basis in the Build Settings pane. Select either your project or one of its targets and click on Build Settings. If you want to define your own settings, scroll to the bottom of that pane and look for the "User-Defined" section, where you can add your own settings.

If you want to set environment variables (and arguments) that will be in effect when your program is running, hold down the Option key and choose Product->Run..., at which point you'll get a window that allows you to define environment variables and arguments.

Comment: I am talking about things like C_INCLUDE_PATH, CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH, LIBRARY_PATH etc. I just wanted to know what these and any others should be set to for doing terminal based compiling.